# Bulk update of custom field value in salesforce object failing due to custom validations and triggers

Tags: custom-field, sobject, exception, bulk-api, externalid

I added a custom field to opportunity salesforce object. It's name is externalId__c.

The field is added to the object. However when I am trying to update the value of externalId__c for all the records, I am getting FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION and (CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER). These rules are set on other fields of records and not on externalId__c.

How to update all records with externalId__c values?

Comment: The error message you are receiving suggests that there is a custom validation rule or a flow trigger that is preventing the update of the externalId__c field. Please check [How to Fix FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION Error](https://automationchampion.com/2022/04/17/how-to-fix-field_custom_validation_exception-error-2/)

Comment: You cannot update the record if validation rules are on any of the object field and rules is failing. You need to deactivate the rule and then try to update data or provide correct values to the failing fields.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter which fields you are or aren't updating. Any update to a record will cause *all of the validation rules* to be evaluated (along with update triggers, and potentially workflow/process builder/flow).

Your only real recourse here is to bring your existing records into compliance with your validation rules.

Comment: I suppose it could be possible that your org has explicitly built in a bypass mechanism for each individual validation rule, but I get the feeling you probably don't. It's probably a coin flip as to whether fixing the data would be faster than disabling (and later re-enabling) individual validation rules, and clean data is the much more attractive option.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to update the records you can also deactivate the validation rule, update the records, and reactivate the validation rule, but this will not change the fact that the next time a user or automated process tries to update one of those records, the validation rule will fire again.

You can also refactor the validation rule to NOT fire only when the external ID field is changed, this will allow you to update the external ID field without triggering the rule...